# Return ALL data when DropDownList is NULL

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am trying to fix some error and mistake which was made and I didn't pay attention in time.

I have two dropdowns (`Status` is `bit`) and (`OrgUnitId int 0-9`).

So the problem is when user selects only one record from these two dropdowns and another dropdown is not selected by default return `0`.

But in my example, I want to modify this and create if User select only `Status = 1` it should return record where status is 1 and OrgUnit it should return all data without filtering.

So far I wrote these code for catch `Status` and `OrgUnitId` from DB and display in DropDownMenu

```cs
public void FillOrgUnit()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string com = "SELECT DISTINCT OrgUnitID FROM tblZaposleni_AD ORDER BY OrgUnitID ASC";
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        ddlOrgUnit.DataSource = dt;
        ddlOrgUnit.DataTextField = "OrgUnitID";
        ddlOrgUnit.DataValueField = "OrgUnitID";
        ddlOrgUnit.DataBind();
        ddlOrgUnit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Izaberi Org Jedinicu --", "NULL"));
    }
}

public void FillStatus()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string com = "SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM tblZaposleni_AD";
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        ddlStatus.DataSource = dt;
        ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Status";
        ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Status";
        ddlStatus.DataBind();
        ddlStatus.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Izaberi Status --", "NULL"));
    }
}
```

And here is my main function for filtering data

```cs
private void GetReports(XtraReport report)
{
    try
    {
        string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string strproc = "TestReport";

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue;
            sda.Fill(ds);

            string[] arrvalues = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

            for (int loopcounter = 0; loopcounter < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; loopcounter++)
            {
                //assign dataset values to array
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["PrezimeIme"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["NetworkLogin"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["Status"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["OrgUnitID"].ToString();
            }

            report.DataSource = ds;
            report.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

For better understanding what I want and where the problem is I wrote this stored procedure:

```sql
DECLARE @Status bit = 1,
        @OrgJed int 
BEGIN
    SELECT PrezimeIme, NetworkLogin, Status, OrgUnitId, DT_Creat, DT_Modif
    FROM [DesignSaoOsig1].[dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
    WHERE (@Status IS NULL OR Status = @Status) 
      AND (@OrgJed IS NULL OR OrgUnitID = @OrgJed)
END
```

And here is the result of this stored procedure:

[image: Result of stored procedure]

And here is what I get as result in View

[image: Result in View]

Comment: You need to change your stored procedure so that based on the value passed in you in execute a different query (i.e. including a predicate or not). Or create a different stored procedure which returns everything and then do the value check in your application and execute whichever stored procedure is appropriate.

Comment: As I see and As I tested my store procedure work great ! Only problem is C# code behind.

Comment: Your question is really unclear then... If your stored procedure is fine and returns what you want, why is it relevant? Can you explain what is wrong with your C# code? What output are you getting, what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like when the ALL option is selected, that you are setting the parameter values to the string "NULL", rather than DBNull.Value.

Try replacing this:

```
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue;
```

With this:

```
if (ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "NULL")
   sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = DBNull.Value;
else
   sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;


if (ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue == "NULL")
     sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
else
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue;
```